# Terraform Service Account Impersonation Issue with GCP

Tags: impersonation, terraform-provider-gcp

I have been trying to get service account impersonation working with my GCP projects and have hit an issue that I don't quite understand.

I have a terraform admin GCP project where the service account I am impersonating resides.  This service account has admin privileges over all other GCP projects.

What I am trying to achieve is as a GCP user deploy to GCP projects without the use of service account keys so that we do not have to worry about the keys being compromised.

The GCP user in this case myself has the correct permissions applied to impersonate the service account, however when performing an apply to deploy a resource such as adding IAM role membership to an existing service account which I do not have the privileges to do generates an error as it does not appear to be trying to deploy under the security context of the service account which does have the required permissions.

First of all I am using a windows host for deployment and I intialise the environment with a custom powershell script as I am using a remote state stored in a GCS bucket, the script pretty much does this:

```
$bucket="bck-xxxxx-xxxx-state"
$prefix="dev"
$varfile="terraform.dev-tfvars"
gcloud auth application-default login

terraform init `
  -backend-config="bucket=$bucket" `
  -backend-config="prefix=$prefix" `
  -var-file="$varfile"
```

The main.tf is configured as follows:

```
provider "google" {
}
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
  }
}

data "google_service_account_access_token" "default" {
 provider = google
 target_service_account = "tfadmin-xxx-xxx@xxx-tfadmin-xxx-xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
 scopes = ["userinfo-email", "cloud-platform"]
 lifetime = "300s"
}

data "google_client_openid_userinfo" "me" { }

#output who am authenticated as
output "source-email" {
  value = "${data.google_client_openid_userinfo.me.email}"
}

provider "google" {
  alias = "impersonated"
  access_token = data.google_service_account_access_token.default.access_token
  project     = "xxxx-tfadmin-xxx-xxxx"
}

data "google_client_openid_userinfo" "thenewme" {
  provider = google.impersonated
}

#output the service account I am impersonating
output "target-email" {
  value = "${data.google_client_openid_userinfo.thenewme.email}"
}
```

After running a terraform init the intialisation process returns success.

Running a terraform plan returns sucessfull, but when I try and apply the changes I get the following:

```
Error: Batch "iam-project-xxxx-xxxxx-dev-xxxx modifyIamPolicy" for request "Create IAM Members roles/storage.legacyBucketReader serviceAccount:svc-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-sts@xxxx-xxxx-dev-xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com for \"project \\\"xxxx-xxxx-dev-xxxx\\\"\"" returned error: batch request and retry as single request failed - final error: Error applying IAM policy for project "xxxx-xxxxx-dev-xxxx": Error 
setting IAM policy for project "xxxx-xxxxx-dev-xxxx": googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden. To debug individual requests, try disabling batching: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/guides/provider_reference.html#enable_batching
```

If I try and run an apply when there is nothing to be added, changed or destroyed my main.tf file does output what I would expect with myself as the source-email and the terraform admins service account as the target-email:

```
Outputs:

source-email = rxxxxx.txxxx@xxxx.co.uk
target-email = xxxx-tfadmin-xxxx-xxx@xxx-tfadmin-xxxx-xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

So I assume that the impersonation is not working properly although it appears as though I should be impersonating the account as expected.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the service account doesn't have enough permission.  googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden. Otherwise, terraform script is not able to access the service account key is not accessible.

Comment: I should have posted back that I got this resolved.  The issue is not with the service account but the fact that you have to state in the resource to use impersonation when creating it. For example:

Comment: module "composer-svc-acc" {
    source = "./modules/iam/serviceAccounts/svcComposer"
    projectid = var.project
    accountid = "svc-${var.env}-cp"
    #TBD When we no longer require service account impersonation this section can be removed.
    providers={google = google.impersonated}
}